# Normalized values in RGB raster using a function

Tags: r, raster, r-raster

I'd like to applied a function to a RGB raster, first standardized the original values using the formula `DNstd = (DN-mean(DN)/sd(DN)` and second the normalization process but now using the formula `DNnor = 255*(DNstd-min(DNstd)/(max(DNstd)-min(DNstdmin))` without successes. I don't wanted to apply by layer, but to all the raster (`r`) in a single function. In my example:

```
 # Create a RBG raster
library(raster)
r1 <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10) 
values(r1) <- rpois(100, 150)
r2 <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10) 
values(r2) <- rpois(100, 200)
r3 <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10) 
values(r3) <- rpois(100, 150)
r <- stack(r1, r2, r3)
names(r)=c("R","G","B")
r
# class      : RasterStack 
# dimensions : 10, 10, 100, 3  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
# resolution : 36, 18  (x, y)
# extent     : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
# names      :   R,   G,   B 
# min values : 124, 170, 126 
# max values : 183, 235, 181 

# Standardized the values using the first DNstd = (DN-DNmean)/DNstd 
#and second Normalized the values using now DNnor = 255*(DNstd-DNstdmin)/(DNstdmax-DNstdmin)
DNnor <- function(img, i, j, k) {
  bi <- img[[i]]
  bj <- img[[j]]
  bk <- img[[k]]
  bi_std <- (bi-mean(bi))/sd(bi) 
  bj_std <- (bj-mean(bj))/sd(bj)
  bk_std <- (bk-mean(bk))/sd(bk)
  bi_nor <- 255*(bi_std-min(bi_std))/(max(bi_std)-min(bi_std))
  bj_nor <- 255*(bj_std-min(bj_std))/(max(bj_std)-min(bj_std))
  bk_nor <- 255*(bk_std-min(bk_std))/(max(bk_std)-min(bk_std))
  return(bi_nor, bj_nor, bk_nor)
}
normalized_image <- DNnor(r, 1, 2, 3)
# Error in as.double(x) : 
# cannot coerce type 'S4' to vector of type 'double'
```

Please, any help with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example data

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10) 
set.seed(1)
r1 <- setValues(r, rpois(100, 150))
r2 <- setValues(r, rpois(100, 200))
r3 <- setValues(r, rpois(100, 150))
r <- stack(r1, r2, r3)
names(r)=c("R","G","B")
```

With these example data, the simple solution is to use `stretch`

```
a <- stretch(r)
```

Also see:

```
plotRGB(r, stretch="lin")
```

More generally, your algorithm may be the same as using `stretch` after using `scale`

```
a <- scale(r) |> stretch()
```

If you want to write your own function, you need to recognize the difference between global computation (a single statistic for all cells, using `cellStats`) and local computation (a new value for each cell). For example:

```
norfun <- function(x) {
    rmean <- cellStats(x, "mean")
    rsd <- cellStats(x, "sd")
    bstd <- (x-rmean)/rsd
    brng <- cellStats(bstd, "range")
    as.vector((255 / diff(brng))) * (bstd - brng[1,])
}

b <- norfun(r)

# same values
plot(a, b)
```

Also note that `cellStats(x, "mean")` is the memory-safe equivalent to `mean(values(x))`

You can also do this with `terra`

```
library(terra)
R <- rast(r)
A <- scale(R) |> stretch()

norfun2 <- function(x) {
    rmean <- unlist(global(x, "mean"))
    rsd <- unlist(global(x, "sd"))
    bstd <- (x-rmean)/rsd
    brng <- t(as.matrix(global(bstd, "range")))
    as.vector((255 / diff(brng))) * (bstd - brng[1,])
}
B <- norfun2(R)

plot(c(A,B), rast(stack(a, b)))
```

Note that `norfun2` does not treat each layer separately. If you wanted or needed to do that, you could write a function for a single layer and apply that to all. Here an example with a simplified function, where you are not concerned about memory limitations, so you can use `values()` to create a vector of cell values.

```
norf <- function(x, ...) {
  v <- values(x)
  v <- (v - mean(v)) / sd(v)
  setValues(x, (255 / (max(v)-min(v))) * (v-min(v)))
}

# `sapp` loops over layers
z <- sapp(R, norf)
```

I do

```
(255 / (max(v)-min(v))) * (v-min(v)))
```

Rather then

```
255 * (v-min(v))) / (max(v)-min(v)))
```

To pre-compute constants, and this safe some time by doing fewer computations on the entire vector.

Answer (score 3):

Please find the reprex below which shows one possible solution

Two preliminary remarks :

1. First problem: a function can only return one object. So `return(obj1, obj2, obj3)` is not possible. So you need to build the resulting `stack` raster inside the function and `return` it at the end of the function.
2. Second problem: a raster stack is a `S4 object` type. So, accessing values with `img[[i]]` is not possible. You have to use the following syntax `img[[i]]@data@values`. Note the difference between...

```r
r[[1]]
#> class      : RasterLayer 
#> dimensions : 10, 10, 100  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
#> resolution : 36, 18  (x, y)
#> extent     : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
#> source     : memory
#> names      : R 
#> values     : 113, 185  (min, max)
```

...and

```r
r[[1]]@data@values
#>   [1] 128 150 153 151 148 143 150 147 155 147 140 140 148 153 162 152 142 156
#>  [19] 163 159 140 140 138 151 173 116 142 136 164 148 148 168 141 149 139 138
#>  [37] 164 144 160 135 147 145 132 152 149 123 124 167 177 144 165 141 156 185
#>  [55] 138 128 149 163 147 157 168 158 150 149 166 127 149 163 161 169 147 170
#>  [73] 160 137 160 129 166 140 135 162 165 145 150 155 152 129 139 136 143 156
#>  [91] 149 145 145 157 150 147 156 144 156 113
```

So, please find below the solution I suggest

**Reprex**

- Code of your function

```r
library(raster)

DNnor <- function(img, i, j, k) {
  bi <- img[[i]]@data@values
  bj <- img[[j]]@data@values
  bk <- img[[k]]@data@values
  bi_std <- (bi-mean(bi))/sd(bi) 
  bj_std <- (bj-mean(bj))/sd(bj)
  bk_std <- (bk-mean(bk))/sd(bk)
  bi_nor <- 255*(bi_std-min(bi_std))/(max(bi_std)-min(bi_std))
  bj_nor <- 255*(bj_std-min(bj_std))/(max(bj_std)-min(bj_std))
  bk_nor <- 255*(bk_std-min(bk_std))/(max(bk_std)-min(bk_std))
  
  r1n <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10)
  values(r1n) <- bi_nor
  r2n <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10)
  values(r2n) <- bj_nor
  r3n <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10)
  values(r3n) <- bk_nor
  
  rn <- stack(r1n, r2n, r3n)
  
  return(rn)
}
```

- Output of the function

```r
normalized_image <- DNnor(r, 1, 2, 3)

normalized_image
#> class      : RasterStack 
#> dimensions : 10, 10, 100, 3  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
#> resolution : 36, 18  (x, y)
#> extent     : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
#> names      : layer.1, layer.2, layer.3 
#> min values :       0,       0,       0 
#> max values :     255,     255,     255
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: You should *never* use syntax like `img[[i]]@data@values`. First because there may be no values there (they typically are in a file); second because that may not be memory-safe.  If you are not concerned about memory limitations, you could extract the cell values you with  `values(img[[1]])`

Comment: Thank you very much @Robert Hijmans for your specific feedback and more generally for the time spent sharing your knowledge around the `raster` and `terra` libraries. In particular, your comment will allow me to correct a very questionable approach to getting the values! As the saying goes, one learns every day ;-) Cheers.

Comment: You are welcome, and of course, we all learn here. In my view directly reading the values of slots `@` is either bad use or bad design (there are exceptions). Writing to a slot is a real no-no, because the design may be that a change in one slot should affect others as well.

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply and your guidance. I will indeed modify an old script to avoid bad surprises!!! I take advantage of this comment to ask you a little more information. Reading the answer you gave, I understand incidentally that the `stretch()` function does not load the raster in memory at all unlike a manually designed function that calls `values()` internally. Did I understand correctly? And if so, what is/are the "strategy(ies)" if one wants to manually design a function that avoids (or minimizes) memory problems as much as possible?

Comment: both raster and terra will read and process large datasets in chunks if necessary. In the small example used for this question there is no difference. But it is generally better to be safe than sorry. To be memory safe, use your custom function with the functions that come with the packages, such as the `_app` family in `terra`. The case at hand is more complex because _global_ statistics cannot be computed in chunks. You could, however, pre-compute them.

Comment: O.K. I see. Thank you so much for this lead...which I will fully explore in 2022! I'd like to take this moment to wish you all the best for this upcoming year. And thanks again for your help. Cheers.